# How can I make a Symfony2 configuration setting mandatory if another one is set?

Tags: symfony

Given a Symfony2 configuration:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme');        

$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->booleanNode('enableErrorReport')
            ->defaultFalse()
        ->end()
        ->arrayNode('errorReportAdresses')
            ->info('a list of commaseparated email addresses')
            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

How can I make `errorReportAdresses` mandatory only if `enableErrorReport` is true?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Optional Sections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#optional-sections) is that are you looking for. Foe example you can see to configuration of [FrameworkBundle profiler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L141).

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('errorReportAdresses')
            ->canBeEnabled() 
            ->info('a list of commaseparated email addresses')
            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

Comment: Thanks, this means I don't need `enableErrorReport`, which seems a good solution. But I have to deal with a legacy app that's relying on these setting. Is there any other way?